# Evil-emacs: how to select last pasted text (like gv)?

Tags: evil, copy-paste

How do I visually select the last pasted text with `evil-emacs`?

`gv` reselects the last visual selection. I'd like a function/snippet that does the same for my last pasted text.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for someone to write you a package...

Comment: I was thinking st like this had to exist. Will try to do it myself then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my `.vimrc` I have

```
nnoremap <leader>v '[V']
```

to do exactly this.

Amazingly, the sequence `'[V']` works in `evil` just fine. To have a shortcut in Emacs, I wrote the following function:

```el
(defun my/evil-select-pasted ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((start-marker (evil-get-marker ?\[))
        (end-marker (evil-get-marker ?\])))
        (evil-visual-select start-marker end-marker)))
```

The function can be bound to e.g. `<leader>v` using `evil-leader`:

```el
(evil-leader/set-key "v" 'my/evil-select-pasted)
```

I'm relatively new to Emacs, so this might not be ideal, but it works for me.

**How I got there:**

`C-h k '` shows that `'` runs `evil-goto-mark-line`. Looking at the source in `evil-commands.el` shows that `evil-goto-mark-line` uses `evil-goto-mark`, which itself makes use of the `evil-get-marker` function. Looking at `evil-states.el`, found with `C-h k V`, leads to the `evil-visual-select` function.

Comment: Does not work in spacemacs, but accepting all the same, since I specified evil :)

Comment: works for me in latest spacemacs, dev branch.

Answer (score 3):

When using @andreas solution to select last pasted text and tried to change indentation on it and then repeating the indentation with `.` (`evil-repeat`) it gave me errors. I had to modify the function to be like this, which now works fine for me:

```el
(defun evil-select-pasted ()
  "Visually select last pasted text."
  (interactive)
  (evil-goto-mark ?\[)
  (evil-visual-char)
  (evil-goto-mark ?\]))
```

Answer (score 1):

The function in [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/21093/30562) of @Andreas didn't work correctly for my spacemacs config
I found a [answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/6lyjg3/evil_select_text_as_region_after_pasting_yanking/) on reddit works more correct:

```
(defun nh-evil/select-last-paste ()
  (interactive)
  (when (not evil-last-paste)
    (user-error "No last paste to highlight"))
  (let ((beg (nth 3 evil-last-paste))
        (end (nth 4 evil-last-paste)))
    (evil-visual-select beg end)))

(define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "i v") 'nh-evil/select-last-paste)
```

Then you could do in evil normal state: `viv` (just like `vig`, `vit`, `viw`) to select just pasted region (with evil-paste-after or other related commands)