# How to select last pasted text

Tags: copy-paste, selection

How can I select the last pasted text with regular Emacs?

I would like to do the same thing as this [Q&A](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19330), but I don't use evil mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When emacs pastes ("yanks") text, it puts a mark at the start of the text, so selecting it can be done using `exchange-point-and-mark`, bound to <kbd>C-xC-x</kbd> by default.

Comment: Booya, that's the trick.